# What does symbol sequence "#$" mean in Ruby and where to use it?

Tags: ruby

There is an example in [the book](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/):

```
"Seconds/day: #{24*60*60}" # => Seconds/day: 86400
"#{'Ho! '*3}Merry Christmas!" # => Ho! Ho! Ho! Merry Christmas!
"This is line #$." # => This is line 3
```

But when I try to implement the third line's symbol `#$` it in a separate file, it prints smth strange. Here's my file `str2.rb`:

```
puts "Hello, World #$."
puts "Hello, World #$"
puts "#$"
```

Now I run it (in Win XP console):

```
C:\ruby\sbox>ruby str2.rb
Hello, World 0
Hello, World ["enumerator.so", "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/encdb.so", "C:/Rai
lsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/windows_1251.so", "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/trans/transdb.so", "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defau
lts.rb", "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/rbconfig.rb", "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/l
ib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb", "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems
/exceptions.rb", "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb",
 "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb", "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9
.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb", "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/utf_16l
e.so", "C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so", "C:/RailsInstaller/Ru
by1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/trans/single_byte.so"]
puts
```

I've found that `#$.` (the period is mandatory) shows the line number only in Interactive Ruby Console. Used in file it produces `0` on any line. But why all that text is printed if I use symbols like this `"#$" \n "#$"`?

Also such a code in a file:

```
puts "Hello, World #$" ## without period at the end
```

produces such an error:

```
C:\ruby\sbox>ruby str2.rb
str2.rb:3: unterminated string meets end of file
```

What does `#$` mean? Where and how to use it?

Answer (score 6):

`"#$."` is shorthand for `"#{$.}"`, or the interpolation of a global variable. Similarly there is `#@` for an instance variable & `#@@` for a class variable.

The problem with what you have is that the second `"` in `"#$"` is *not* interpreted as the closing quote for the string, but instead as part of the global variable name being interpolated (`$"`). To make it more clear how your code is actually being interpreted, I’ll use string literals in place of what Ruby thinks are string delimiters:

```
puts %(Hello, World #$.)
puts %(Hello, World #$"
puts )#$"
```

As you can see, this is where the array printed comes from (it’s the contents of `$"`) as well as the “puts” string at the end. The `#$"` at the end of your code is interpreted as a comment. (Note that the second string is spanning—and including—the newline between lines two and three.)

If you actually want to print `#$` as a string, you have to escape part of it or use a single-quoted string:

- `"\#$"  #=> "#$"`
- `"#\$"  #=> "#$"`
- `'#$'   #=> "#$"`

Simply placing `#$` in an interpolated string without escaping is not valid, as can be seen by using string literals:

```
%(#$)  #=> #<SyntaxError: (eval):2: syntax error, unexpected $undefined
       #   %(#$)
       #      ^>
```

Comment: What about this `puts "#$end"` and `puts "#{$}"` ??

Comment: @codeit There’s nothing special about the first—it prints the contents of the global variable `$end`. And the second is not a complete expression.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby a global variables are defined using dollar sign.

```
$foo = "bar"
```

There are some pre-defined globals such as

```
# last line number seen by interpreter
$.
```

I think you are just missing the period. You can insert a variable into a string using -

```
"line #{$.}"
```

or shorthand

```
"line #$."
```